# How can I find/install a package that appears not to be available

Tags: 64-bit, package-management

I'm trying to install the novell iPrint client on ubuntu 10.10, which comes as an rpm package and so needs to be installed via alien. One of its requirements to work properly seems to be a package called *libglitz-glx1*. This package seems to be available for several distributions but not in the main repository for Ubuntu 10.10.

The package does seem to be available for the 32 bit version of ubuntu but I'm running 64 bit. Is it possible to download and use the 32 bit version and rebuild it for 64 bit or is it not that simple...

Simply put: how can I install *libglitz-glx1*.

Comment: I dont think you can. If its there, it's there. If it's not, its not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Glitz OpenGL 2D graphics library is no longer included in Ubuntu > 10.10. However you can still download and install the [am64 Debian package for libglitz-glx1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/amd64/libglitz-glx1/0.5.6-1build1) built for 10.04 from Launchpad. In the URL given you will also find the dependencies that need to be met:

Before installing `libglitz-glx1` you obviously need to install `libglitz1` that can also be downloaded [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/libglitz1/0.5.6-1build1).

**You need to find out yourself if these libraries are safe to run, as they are not tested for  conflicts with other packages from Maverick.**

Answer (score 2):

Try the amd64 version of lucid http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libglitz-glx1
For what i have seen the package will be compatible since it needs a certain version **or higher** which you should have already.